# Should SPA talk to auth server directly or resource server?

Tags: architecture, oauth2, single-page-apps

I have an angular based SPA, and backend resource server is written in springboot. I have integrated keycloak to provide OIDC support. Currently the app talks to auth server for login, (supplies credentials) and gets a token, which is uses further to access resource server APIs. But I don't want end users to be aware of the auth server and try to game it bombarding multiple requests or trying bruteforce. In my past I had exposed a rest endpoint in resource server, which acted like a pass thru and transmitted the details to authserver and back to the client APP. Also I want to disable the authserver admin console in production.

I am wondering which is the correct design choice a) client app directly talking to authserver for token issue and resource server for validation OR b) client app talks to resource server and then resource server talks to authserver for issuing token as well as validation.

Comment: If a client is eager to bombard your auth server, would they not be equally eager to bombard your resource server? Is that going to be less of a problem?

Comment: @Flater From my understanding, an authserver can be shared across multiple resource servers, not just my own resource server. So in my opinion DDoS on authserver is more impactful than DDoS on my resource server. I may be wrong here, feel free to correct me.

Comment: I wasn't implying an opinion, just asking if you had considered it.

Answer (score 3):

Either approach can be entirely reasonable. But I'm with you that it probably makes sense to integrate auth as an endpoint as part of your normal APIs, instead of presenting is as a separate server. It may very well be a separate server, but you can hide that from the clients e.g. via a reverse proxy or other gateway, or by the passthrough endpoint that you have used before.

For example, you might have configured Nginx as a reverse proxy, providing TLS termination and passing some routes to your auth server, with other routes being passed to your main backend.

```
location /auth/realms/ {
  proxy_pass http://internal-auth-server/realms/;
}

location / {
  proxy_pass http://main-backend-server;
}
```

I wouldn't expect any notable security differences from this. You are correct to be concerned about potential attacks, and it does make sense to prevent public access to admin interfaces. While the auth server by itself should be robust enough, you can combine various techniques to help reduce risks.

- control access to admin interfaces via proper authorization. Persons with access to admin interfaces should have strong passwords (likely using a password manager), and use multi-factor authentication (MFA): at least TOTP via some app, but ideally a FIDO/Webauthn security key. Strong passwords are practically immune to brute-forcing, and FIDO/Webauthn is highly resistant against phishing.
- use firewall rules, reverse proxies, and so on, to only expose admin interfaces on an internal network. For example, an admin who wants to log in to the admin interface might first have to log in to a VPN. This is insufficient as a security measure by itself, but it reduces your attack surface. For example, the above Nginx reverse proxy configuration prevents the route `http://internal-auth-server/admin` to be accessed through the proxy.
- implement or enable rate-limiting. This is not just about protecting your servers, but also your users. You might implement rate limiting as part of a reverse proxy, but Keycloak itself also has built-in rate limiting options that might be useful. You could tie some limits to the number of failed log-in attempts from a certain IP-address. However, this can only slow down attackers, and does not provide real security (especially as determined attackers will have a practically infinite supply of IP addresses through their botnets). Note that availability is also a security goal, so preventing one user from logging in just because someone else is brute-forcing their account credentials might be counter-productive.

Comment: Thanks @amon for your answer and valuable inputs, this is really helpful.